# Поиск по базе данных через php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Как сделать поиск по БД, как сделать так чтобы было true, если запись есть или false, если записи нет?

Comment: Ну, прочитать первую главу любого учебника по sql?

Comment: А где можно найти этот учебник по SQL?

Answer (score -1):

table = твоя таблица. title поле по которую происходит поиск

```
function checkExist($name)
{
  $con = connectvar();
  mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);
  $result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM table WHERE title='$name' LIMIT 1");

  if(mysql_fetch_array($result) !== false)
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

Это как пример. Вообще учебников по SQL очень много хороших, посмотри этот [Интерактивный учебник по SQL](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/)

Comment: Срочно читать про SQL инъекции